# React Native NFC opens a browser

Tags: react-native

I have added NFC (https://github.com/whitedogg13/react-native-nfc-manager) followed the procedure as mentioned but on the first time it work perfect on the second time it open a NFC url in a browser.

does anyone else faced the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that only for the first time the app listens to the NFC event, while the second time the android system takes control and opens the URL in the browser.
Seems that either by explicitly calling *unregisterTagEvent* or somehow implicitly the app stops listening to the NFC event

Comment: any suggestion, that how should I handle?